# IE 11 becomes unresponsive while running Java web application

Tags: java, internet-explorer, web, browser

My users are experiencing IE 11 unresponsiveness while running my Java web application.  The application produces a large amount of PDF data. Is there a way to resolve this issue within the application or through user computer/IE settings? Thanks.

Comment: Before you can fix the problem, you need to work out the cause for the "unresponsiveness".  There are many possible causes.  Get out your JVM monitoring tools and start looking ...

Comment: It’s caused when users open many PDFs in different tabs. Thanks.

Comment: It appears IE holds on to cache and becomes unresponsive when it reaches certain limit.  Restarting IE is a temporary fix. Others users are not affected during the time. Thanks.

Comment: If you are sure that cache limit cause this issue than you can try to increase the cache size from Internet Options-> General Tab-> under browsing history-> click on Settings button. Than try to set the 'Disk space to use' option to increase cache size. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/PJjyfVXc/2.gif

Comment: Great.  Will give it a try.  Thanks.